From Address is not applied when mail is sent in Laravel Version 11
I want to send mail from different address.
I changed in this code but address (address: 'jeffrey@example.com') in following code but isn't applied.
It just show address by use MAIL_USERNAME in env file
public function envelope(): Envelope
{
    return new Envelope(
        from: new Address(address: 'jeffrey@example.com', name: 'Jeffrey Way'),
    );
}


Clear cache & config.Then try

I used but it's not changed.

If the mail is generated in a queue it could still use old code you had when the queue started. After every change to your job code your should restart your queue using php artisan queue:restart

I run php artisan queue:restart but It just update name, address is not updated
